# J'avaScript not in HTML

Tags: javascript, environment

I'm trying to develop an application user-interface within an iOS application. The iOS application supports JavaScript and SVG; this iOS application also has an editor in which I am developing the interface. The idea is to use SVG for the graphics (developed in Illustrator or InkScape) and then JavaScript to handle animations, calculation or logic.

With that being said I am familiar with using JavaScript to manipulate the DOM of an HTML. I cant seem to do the same in this environment. Common methods like `getElementById`, `ownerDocument`, `setInterval` don't work. In general common document or window level methods that are used in HTML do not seem to work.

So I'm guessing that this is because there is no DOM for JS to interact with. What then could the equivalent be? Is there some sort of abstraction/hierarchy of that javascript defaults to when its not being used in conjunction with HTML?

Comment: I haven't messed with iOS applications much as of yet, but when you say the "iOS application supports JavaScript and SVG", how do you mean? Is it a web browser? Is it using a web browser control of some form? Is there an error message when you try to use those Javascript methods?

Comment: Well I'm not familiar with Lua, but its widely used for similar purposes. World of Warcraft addons are written in lua, that interact with the addons GUI designed in XML. I've also seen use of Lua+XML in application like Rainlendar. Something tells me theres some lib about that out there ready to be used.

Comment: OP -- 
@Tom There are no errors generated, it just does not run. It is an iOS application that you upload your application to it then it runs it on iOS. So what I make is uploaded to this iOS app and then I open this iOS app and it runs/displays what I made. 

I said supports meaning I can import SVG and write JS code in the editor. It has a graphical and logical part to it; graphical=SVG/PNG logical=JS/JQuery.

Havenard I will look into Lua, never heard of it myself.

Comment: @nemo, is said application in PhoneGap?

Comment: @Tom Nope. PhoneGap looks interesting though! the said application is mySCADA

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no HTML, these methods will have no effect on whatever your API's equivalent of a DOM is. The appropriate methods will vary based upon the application.

Comment: Thanks Scott. Is there any way to just hack it and kind of determine what this API's heirarchy or DOM is? Id like to think there is something because it uses SVG and JS... like a methodology I can employ to help me determine 'where the ceiling is' so to speak, or who executes who.

Comment: This would be something to check with your framework's documentation about.

Comment: the documentation does not go into this much detail. BUT I did find out that whatever script I write goes into the function argument of setTimeout(function,timeout) in a 'bigger' program that runs my script.